# Explicit formula for $d_k = 5d_{k−1} + 2$, for all integers $k ≥ 1$ $d_0 = 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to use iteration to figure out the explicit formula for this. The sequence looks like this:

$2,12,62,312$

However, I'm not sure how to approach finding a formula for this.

Comment: Let $d_n=c_n+a+bn$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $d_k+\frac{1}{2}=5(d_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2})$.

Thus, the sequence  $d_k+\frac{1}{2}$ is a geometric series.